# Clear data on empty input - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find a way to check whether my input is cleared in order to clear data.

The logic i'm using for this check is `if (searchTerm.length === 0)` clear input... I've also tried `if (searchTerm === '')` but they don't work. The thing with these logic checks is that the event fires with when the input is cleared and 1 character is added where the length of the string is 0 when it should be 1?

When I console.log my input string length I get `0` for 1 character, `1` for 2 characters and when I completely clear the input I get `1` for 0 characters.

What is the proper way to check for a cleared input value?

Here is my logic:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
    error: null
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state

    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value })

    if (searchTerm.trim() === '') {
      this.props.resetSearch()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { searchTerm, error } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="input-container">
        { error && <p className="invalid">Please Enter Something</p> }
        <input 
          type="text"
          placeholder="search for a repo..."
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          onKeyPress={e => e.key === 'Enter' && this.findRepos(e)}
        />
        <button 
          type="submit" 
          onClick={e => this.findRepos(e)}>
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { fetchRepos, resetSearch })(SearchBar)
```

Comment: What event are you listening for ?

Comment: In your case I would use a controlled component. Have a look at the React docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: @Titus an onChange event

Comment: How do you set `searchTerm` ? Have you tried `event.target.value` ?

Comment: @Titus I added my code

Comment: It seems that you're checking the previous value of the input `const { searchTerm } = this.state`, you should check the current value `const searchTerm = e.target.value`

Comment: try doing your check in callback of setState, then you will get the latest value of searchTerm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { searchTerm } = this.state

  this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value })

  if (searchTerm.trim() === '') {
    this.props.resetSearch()
  }
}
```

You are checking the previous state, not the current input value. Your code should be

```
handleChange = e => {
  const searchTerm = e.target.value;

  this.setState({ searchTerm: searchTerm })

  if (searchTerm.trim() === '') {
    this.props.resetSearch()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I keep forgetting this part of using React.